# Graying out a component in Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

When I click on a checkbox in my Wicket app, some fields need to be grayed out AJAXically.

Comment: Means what???????? Do you mean to disable fields? If yes then use javascript for that.

Comment: @kvijayhari yes, but wicket provides utilities for that, no need to do it manually with javascript

Comment: you should also write longer, more descriptive questions. I no longer answer questions like these because nine times out of ten, some critical piece of information specific to your/the OP's case is missing that invalidates generic answers.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Component.setEnabled(false)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29).

Provide more context if you need more details.

Comment: Or use Component.isEnabled() with conditions, depending on your page composition and ui needs.

Comment: @ireddick yup, that's one of the things I would have said if there was more context :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the Wicket Ajax way...

```
CheckBox check = new CheckBox("check");
final TextField field = new TextField("text");

check.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        field.setEnabled((Boolean) getComponent().getDefaultModelObject());
        target.addComponent(field);
    }
});
```

However, this involves a server round trip.  Perhaps you'd prefer a client-side jQuery solution.